# Constructor dependency Injection issue

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, javabeans, creation

I am learning DI and new to spring while trying out CI I have written following code and I think I am correct in syntax still it's showing bean creation error.  why it is unable to create bean..??
The code is

Constuctor.java

```
package beans;

public class Constructor {
private String name;
private int age;
private String email;

public void Constructor(String name, int age, String email){
    this.name=name;
    this.age=age;
    this.email=email;    
}

public void show()
{
    System.out.println("Name = "+name);
    System.out.println("Age = "+age);
    System.out.println("Email = "+email);
}

}
```

spring.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN"
        "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">
        <!-- Ordered parameters -->

        <beans>

        <bean id="t" class="beans.Constructor">

        <constructor-arg value="Alok"/>
        <constructor-arg  value="24"/>
        <constructor-arg  value="alok@gmail.com"/>

        </bean>

        </beans>
```

Const_main.java

```
package test;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import beans.Constructor;

public class Const_main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       ApplicationContext ap= new  ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("resources/spring.xml");
        Constructor c = (Constructor)ap.getBean("t");
            c.show();

    }

}
```

it's giving the following error

```
Jun 29, 2017 3:16:45 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@b1a58a3: startup date [Thu Jun 29 15:16:45 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
Jun 29, 2017 3:16:45 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [resources/spring.xml]
Jun 29, 2017 3:16:46 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext refresh
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: **Error creating bean with name 't' defined in class path resource [resources/spring.xml]: Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)
Exception in thread "main"** org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 't' defined in class path resource [resources/spring.xml]: Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:240)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at test.Const_main.main(Const_main.java:10)
```

Comment: add index = "0" / index = "1" in each <constructor-arg value="Alok"/> line

Comment: but I think that is to be used when we are not parameters order..I am passing the  parameters in the same order as they are defined in Constructor...then it should run properly..??

Comment: yeah, but I think Spring is not looking at your parameters order, instead it decides only on the basis of parameters types. So just to remove ambiguities, its better to mention either parameters types or more preferably parameters indexes. check this: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/constructor_based_dependency_injection.htm

Comment: Yeah..I tried using that also but it shows no change..

Comment: <bean id="t" class="beans.Constructor">
   
      <constructor-arg value="Alok" index="0"/>
      <constructor-arg  value="24" index="1"/>
       <constructor-arg  value="alok@gmail.com" index="2"/>
   
       </bean>

Comment: you declared your constructor like : public void Constructor(String name, int age, String email){} is this a constructor? :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN"
"http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">
<!-- Ordered parameters -->

<beans>

<bean id="t" class="beans.Constructor">

<constructor-arg>
  <value>Alok</value>
</constructor-arg>
<constructor-arg>
  <value>24</value>
</constructor-arg>
<constructor-arg>
  <value>alok@gmail.com</value>
</constructor-arg>

</bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use Constructor Dependency Injection without creating any such constructor in your DTO (`Constructor.java`)

The method you defined above:

```
public void Constructor(String name, int age, String email){
    this.name=name;
    this.age=age;
    this.email=email;    
}
```

is just a simple method/function not a constructor, try to remove the word `void`.

### Note:

To remove any ambiguities for constructor matching, it is more prefer to use indexes with constructor's parameters like:

```
    <bean id="t" class="beans.Constructor"> 
      <constructor-arg value="Alok" index="0"/> 
      <constructor-arg value="24" index="1"/> 
      <constructor-arg value="alok@gmail.com" index="2"/> 
   </bean>
```

Comment: Why prefer indexes? I think your first comment regarding constructor defination will solve it.

Comment: @Rohit Yes sure!! without defining proper constructor, it can't be resolved. But after defining constructor, as Spring suggested, to remove ambiguities, its better to define indexes as well. Spring doc says: "hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities"